# Create AD users and assign to a group from a CSV with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am setting up a script to create users on my ad however I am stuck on two things: how to add users to the group and how to create a sharing folder for each user map to the letter P I leave you my csv file and my script I thank you in advance for your feedback

```
Prenom  Nom Fonction    Ou
Karim   Fadil   ingénieur SI    OU=Informatique,DC=AXEPLANE,DC=LOC
Amine   Maldini Technicien  OU=Informatique,DC=AXEPLANE,DC=LOC
Malika  Malinek Dev OU=Informatique,DC=AXEPLANE,DC=LOC
Alberto Talkini Dev OU=Informatique,DC=AXEPLANE,DC=LOC
Bernardo    Lemina  agent   OU=Informatique,DC=AXEPLANE,DC=LOC
Akila   Fahmi   Technicien  OU=Informatique,DC=AXEPLANE,DC=LOC
Amira   Nafima  Technicien  OU=Informatique,DC=AXEPLANE,DC=LOC
```

```
`$CSVFile = "C:\Users\Utilisateurs.csv"
$CSVData = Import-CSV -Path $CSVFile -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 

Foreach($Utilisateur in $CSVData){

    $UtilisateurPrenom = $Utilisateur.Prenom
    $UtilisateurNom = $Utilisateur.Nom
    $UtilisateurLogin = ($UtilisateurPrenom).Substring(0,1) + "." + $UtilisateurNom
    $UtilisateurEmail = "$UtilisateurLogin@axeplane.loc"
    $UtilisateurMotDePasse = "IT-Axeplane@2020"
    $UtilisateurFonction = $Utilisateur.Fonction
    $OU      = $Utilisateur.Ou
    

    # Vérifier la présence de l'utilisateur dans l'AD
    if (Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $UtilisateurLogin})
    {
        Write-Warning "L'identifiant $UtilisateurLogin existe déjà dans l'AD"
    }
    else
    {
        New-ADUser -Name "$UtilisateurNom $UtilisateurPrenom" `
                    -DisplayName "$UtilisateurNom $UtilisateurPrenom" `
                    -GivenName $UtilisateurPrenom `
                    -Surname $UtilisateurNom `
                    -SamAccountName $UtilisateurLogin `
                    -UserPrincipalName "$UtilisateurLogin@axeplane.loc" `
                    -EmailAddress $UtilisateurEmail `
                    -Title $UtilisateurFonction `
                    -Path $OU `
                    -AccountPassword(ConvertTo-SecureString $UtilisateurMotDePasse -AsPlainText -Force) `
                    -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true `
                    -Enabled $true

        Write-Output "Création de l'utilisateur : $UtilisateurLogin ($UtilisateurNom $UtilisateurPrenom)"
    }
    

}`
```

I'm stuck on adding users to the group and creating a personal sharing folder map to the letter P

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your script to include `-HomeDirectory` and `-HomeDrive` parameters.

I've also included `Get-AdGroup` and `Add-AdGroupMember`. You don't have any group details in your CSV so I have put `Get-AdGroup` outside the `foreach` loop. There is no point in iterating over a fixed value.

```
$CSVFile = "C:\Users\Utilisateurs.csv"
$CSVData = Import-CSV -Path $CSVFile -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 


$GroupDn = "CN=MyGroup,OU=Groups,DC=AXEPLANE,DC=LOC
$Server = "dc01.axeplane.loc
$Group = Get-AdGroup -Identity $GroupDn -Server $Server


Foreach($Utilisateur in $CSVData){

    $UtilisateurPrenom = $Utilisateur.Prenom
    $UtilisateurNom = $Utilisateur.Nom
    $UtilisateurLogin = ($UtilisateurPrenom).Substring(0,1) + "." + $UtilisateurNom
    $UtilisateurEmail = "$UtilisateurLogin@axeplane.loc"
    $UtilisateurMotDePasse = "IT-Axeplane@2020"
    $UtilisateurFonction = $Utilisateur.Fonction
    $OU = $Utilisateur.Ou
        
    $HomeDirectory = "\\path\to\share"
    $HomeDrive = "P:"
    

    # Vérifier la présence de l'utilisateur dans l'AD
    if (Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $UtilisateurLogin})
    {
        Write-Warning "L'identifiant $UtilisateurLogin existe déjà dans l'AD"
    }
    else
    {
        $User = New-ADUser -Name "$UtilisateurNom $UtilisateurPrenom" `
                    -DisplayName "$UtilisateurNom $UtilisateurPrenom" `
                    -GivenName $UtilisateurPrenom `
                    -Surname $UtilisateurNom `
                    -SamAccountName $UtilisateurLogin `
                    -UserPrincipalName "$UtilisateurLogin@axeplane.loc" `
                    -EmailAddress $UtilisateurEmail `
                    -Title $UtilisateurFonction `
                    -Path $OU `
                    -AccountPassword(ConvertTo-SecureString $UtilisateurMotDePasse -AsPlainText -Force) `
                    -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true `
                    -Enabled $true `
                    -HomeDirectory $HomeDirectory `
                    -HomeDrive $HomeDrive `
                    -Passthru

        Add-AdGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $User -Server $Server
        
        Write-Output "Création de l'utilisateur : $UtilisateurLogin ($UtilisateurNom $UtilisateurPrenom)"
    }   
}
```

Caveat: I haven't tested the script. E&OE.

Here's a link to the Microsoft documentation on Group membership. They're using `Get-AdUser`, but you're using `New-AdUser`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-3

Comment: thank you very much for your feedback I added the group to my csv file however I have an error on line 5 $GroupDn =CN=MyGroup,OU=Groups,DC=AXEPLANE,DC=LOC missing argument in the list of parameters I don't understand I'll leave you my csv file if you can look please that will be super nice of you ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Group
Globale
Globale
Globale
Globale
Globale
Globale
Globale

Comment: for the mapping it's good it works thank you very much I just have an error on line 46 Add-ADGroupMember: The parameter cannot be processed, because the parameter name “Member” is ambiguous. Possible matches
are: -Members -MemberTimeToLive.
To the character Line:46:44
+ Add-AdGroupMember -Identity $Group -Member $User -Serv ...
+ ~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

Comment: Apologies. I missed off the 's' from -Member. It takes an array so is plural. Fixed in my answer. Here's the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: Can you update your question to include your new CSV and the changes you've made to the script and share any errors, please?

Comment: I would advise to stop using those horrible backticks and start to use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) on cmdlets like New-ADUser that take a lot of parameters. This will make the code a lot cleaner and easier to modify when needed. Also, `New-ADUser` needs the `-PassThru` switch added in order to return the newly created user. Without that, the cmdlet will return nothing [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#outputs)

Comment: Thanks @Theo. -PassThru added. I didn't check the docs :-(. I guess New-AdUser is a good example of when to use splatting. I notice MSFT use it more in their examples these days. I didn't want to change the OPs code too much.

Comment: I put my new version thank you for your feedback

Comment: I succeeded with this script

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, try to avoid using cmdlets where parameters are set on a new line using backticks.
Instead, use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for this which will not only make the code more robust, but also easier to maintain.

Below your code modified to use splatting the parameters to New-ADUser

```
$CSVFile = 'C:\Users\Utilisateurs.csv'
$CSVData = Import-CSV -Path $CSVFile -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8 
$Server  = 'SRV-AD'

foreach ($Utilisateur in $CSVData) {
    $UtilisateurFullName   = '{0} {1}' -f $Utilisateur.Prenom, $Utilisateur.Nom
    $UtilisateurLogin      = '{0}.{1}' -f ($Utilisateur.Prenom).Substring(0,1), $Utilisateur.Nom
    $UtilisateurEmail      = '{0}@axeplane.loc' -f $UtilisateurLogin
    $UtilisateurMotDePasse = 'IT-Axeplane@2020'

    # Vérifier la présence de l'utilisateur dans l'AD
    if (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$UtilisateurLogin'") {
        Write-Warning "L'identifiant $UtilisateurLogin existe déjà dans l'AD"
    }
    else {
        # create a Hashtable with all parameters you need to fill
        $userParams = @{
            Name                  = $UtilisateurFullName
            DisplayName           = $UtilisateurFullName
            GivenName             = $Utilisateur.Prenom
            Surname               = $Utilisateur.Nom
            SamAccountName        = $UtilisateurLogin
            UserPrincipalName     = $UtilisateurEmail
            EmailAddress          = $UtilisateurEmail
            Title                 = $Utilisateur.Fonction
            Path                  = $Utilisateur.Ou
            AccountPassword       = (ConvertTo-SecureString $UtilisateurMotDePasse -AsPlainText -Force)
            ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
            Enabled               = $true
            HomeDirectory         = '\\SRV-AD\Users\{0}'-f $UtilisateurLogin   # set this to match your environment
            HomeDrive             = 'P:'
            PassThru              = $true  # this makes New-ADUser return the newly created user object
        }

        # create the new user and return in variable $User using the Hashtable
        $User = New-ADUser @userParams

        # now add this user to the group stated in the CSV
        $Group = Get-ADGroup -Identity $Utilisateur.Group -Server $Server
        $Group | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $User -Server $Server
    
        Write-Host "Création de l'utilisateur : {0} ({1} {2})" -f $UtilisateurLogin, $Utilisateur.Nom, $Utilisateur.Prenom
    }
}
```